# How to restore MBR and boot windows 7 from GRUB rescue?

Tags: grub, mbr

I have a dualboot system with ubuntu and windows 7, I wanted to remove ubuntu so I removed the linux partition from disk management from windows, after reboot I'm stuck in GRUB rescue. How to boot into windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First boot on your Windows Vista/7/8 installation DVD.

If you have one of the many OEM computers that didn't come with a Windows installation disk, you can get the same effect with a Windows repair disk, which you can download (eg Win7-32bit, Win7 64bit) or create from another Windows Vista/7/8 computer. When you get to the Regional settings, select your Location/Keyboard setting then click next. On the next page, click on "Repair your computer." On the next page, if it finds your Windows installation, make sure it is UNSELECTED before clicking next. Then click on "Command prompt". From there, type in the following 2 commands:

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Comment: I'm on windows 7, can I use a Windows 8 live CD? @Suriya

Comment: Yes you can @Soundarya

Comment: @Suriya only if  the win 7 IS EFI or win 8 dvd is booted in CSM (aka legacy mode)