# How to recover windows system from grub rescue error?

Tags: windows-7, linux, linux-mint

uI have run two OS's (windows 7 n opensuse) in my pc. Later I tried to remove opensuse using minitool partition wizard. When I tried to restart,it is showing an error:grub rescue. I am unable to open any of the OSs now. I deleted 2GB of linux partition using the tool, the reason might b the half process..
Now, how to get back my normal windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restore MBR and boot windows 7 from GRUB rescue?](http://superuser.com/questions/904840/how-to-restore-mbr-and-boot-windows-7-from-grub-rescue)

Answer (score 1):

Insert  your Windows 7 DVD and run **Startup Repair**. Done.